# What is one use case that requires tree-filter instead of index-filter?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

From the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html) `--index-filter`

> ...is similar to the tree filter but does not check out the tree, which makes it much faster.

So, usually I use `--index-filter`. That said, I assume that these aren't just redundant options. What is one use case  that `--tree-filter` could accomplish that `--index-filter` could not accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You can run arbitrary shell commands against a 'real' file tree, which is what you get with `--tree-filter`, whereas any command you run for an `--index-filter` has to be able to work with the Git index itself - ie be very much Git-aware.

So, for instance, you can run `sed` to substitute the contents of files with a `--tree-filter` (for instance removing a password from Git history - tho' [the BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) is better at that), but without a regular filesystem file tree, you'd be reduced to some fairly impressive Git-fu and piping to make the same thing happen directly against the index (reading the contents of relevent blobs, modifying the index with new blobs as required).